# Custom UITableCellView is far too big for my TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In my app I have created a UITableCellView and the layouting with AutoLayout. Adding the cell to my TableView did not show the second label in the beginning. Moving it far to the left showed that the cell is way too wide. Here are the pictures to clarify what I just said:

[image: My UITableCellView]

[image: Emulator picture]

Do I have to set the width of the cell programmatically or why does the cells differ so much in the layout and the emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I have to set the width of the cells programmatically?

- No, the cell takes the width of its parent table view.

What you need to do is add leading and trailing constraints to the labels. For example, on the top cell:

FirstName would need a leading constraint with the constant equal to the amount of space you want (default margins are likely fine) at a high priority.

FirstDate needs to be moved to the right side (I'm guessing that's where you want it) of the cell in your .xib file. Add a trailing constraint with the amount of padding you want, also with a high priority.

Now, add a trailing constraint to the FirstName label over to the FirstDate label. Set it equal to or greater than the distance, with a priority of 999.

Now, no matter the width of the cell, they will be placed on the left and right sides of the cell.